# How to create a tar.gz file in R?

Tags: r

I would create a tar.gz file from R. But the tar function doesn't work me. This is my example code.

```
writeLines('aaaa', 'tmp.txt')
tar('tmp.tar.gz', 'tmp.txt', compression = 'gzip')
```

This code creates a tmp.tar.gz, but tmp.txt doesn't include in the gz file.

Are there any mistakes in my code?

Thanks for any suggestions.

I run this code in windows and linux:

```
#Windows platform
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.0

#Linux platform
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C        
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C           
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] weaana_0.1.0.3874  abind_1.4-0        reshape2_1.4       ncdf4cf_0.1.0.3698 ncdf4_1.10        
[6] stringr_0.6.2      My_0.1.0.4086     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.1 plyr_1.8.1  tools_3.1.0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess you do not have set the `"tar"` environmental variable. The default argument of `tar()` called `tar` is set by a call to `Sys.getenv("tar")`. If it is an empty string, then R's internal `tar` is used (it doesn't work on my system either).

So, you may either `Sys.setenv` the `"tar"` variable, or provide the name of external `tar` command/path manually:

```
tar('tmp.tar.gz', 'tmp.txt', compression = 'gzip', tar="tar")
```

Comment: Hello, i tried to set my tar variable with Sys.setenv(tar = "pathToTarCmd"), it seems to work because i check it with Sys.getenv("tar") which return non null string but when i call tar command as you do it, it does not work, how can i do it ?